# javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets

I've seen this question asked a few times and I've tried all solutions  and nothing helps. I'm trying to use spring to handle my servlet methods but for some reason one of my methods isn't running. The test method is running that takes a string as parameter and returns a string. But the add method that takes the body as a parameter and returns an int isn't working and I get this exception
my web.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
            </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
</listener>
```

my mvc-dispacher-sevlet.xml is

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd"
    >

<!-- Need DI a message into controller, so auto component scan is disabled, 
    to avoid double create the movieController bean. Only controller need this 
    hack. -->
<!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.y2apps.quoteformessenger.webapp"> 
    <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com.y2apps.quoteformessenger.webapp.Movie.*" 
    /> </context:component-scan> -->

<mvc:annotation-driven />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <util:list id="beanList">
            <ref bean="stringHttpMessageConverter" />
            <ref bean="marshallingHttpMessageConverter" />
        </util:list>
    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="stringHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter" />

<bean id="marshallingHttpMessageConverter"
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
    <property name="marshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="castorMarshaller" />
</bean>

<bean id="castorMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.castor.CastorMarshaller" />

    <bean class="com.test.webapp.ClientController">
</bean>
```

my controller is

```
@Controller
public class ClientController implements QuoteService {

@RequestMapping("/test")
public @ResponseBody String getTest(@RequestParam("message") String message) {
    return "Hello " + message;
}
@RequestMapping(Constants.ADD_QUOTES_PATH)
public int add(@RequestBody String csv) {
    System.out.println(csv);
    return 2;
}
```

and the exception I get is

```
[INFO] javax.servlet.ServletException: No adapter for handler [public int com.test.webapp.ClientController.addQuotes(java.lang.String)]: Does your handler implement a supported interface like Controller?
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandlerAdapter(DispatcherServlet.java:1100)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
[INFO]  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:127)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:125)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:98)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:503)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
[INFO]  at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

thank you for your help

Comment: Constants.ADD_QUOTES_PATH value ?

Comment: public static final String ADD_QUOTES_PATH = "/add";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing  @ResponseBody for my method should have been

```
@RequestMapping(Constants.ADD_QUOTES_PATH)
public @ResponseBody int add(@RequestBody String csv) { 
    return 2;
}
```

instead of

```
@RequestMapping(Constants.ADD_QUOTES_PATH)
public int add(@RequestBody String csv) { 
    return 2;
}
```